# компиляция с++ и заголовочный файл

Tags: c++

основной файл: main.cpp

```
#include "file.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    func1();

    return 0;
};
```

заголовочный файл: file.h

```
void func1();
```

file.cpp файл с кодом file.h

```
#include <iostream>
void func1(){
    std::cout << "1";
};
```

так вот при попытке скомпилировать код с помощью команды (g++ main.cpp) выводи сообщение что не знает что за функция func1(), а вот при использовании (g++ main.cpp file.cpp) все работает, так вот закралось сомнение а правильно ли так компилить, поскольку если в дальнейшем в файлов будет от 10 и все их нужно прописывать после (g++ main.cpp ...)? использую MinGW версия gcc-6.3.0

Comment: Не волнуйтесь. Постепенно познакомитесь, что такой make, как объединять файлы в библиотеки и тд и тп...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Совершенно верно, если файлов будет 10, то все 10 придется прописывать в командной строке компилятора

```
g++ file1.cpp file2.cpp ... file9.cpp main.cpp
```

Такая командная строка на самом деле последовательно выполняет два этапа трансляции: сначала *компилирует* индивидуальные `.cpp` файлы в `.o` файлы, а затем *собирает* полученные `.o` файлы в финальную программу.

При желании вы можете использовать опцию `-c` для того, чтобы разделить эти два этапа: сначала скомпилировать `.cpp` файлы в `.o` файлы по одному

```
g++ -c file1.cpp
g++ -c file2.cpp
...
g++ -c file9.cpp
g++ -c main.cpp
```

а затем выполнить финальную сборку. Однако для финальной сброки вам все равно придется передать все полученные `.o` файлы в `g++` (или в `ld`)

```
g++ file1.o file2.o ... file9.o main.o
```

Т.е. как ни верти, некий шаг, на котором вам придется перечислить "много файлов" в командной строке, все равно будет.

Избавиться от чересчур длинных перечислений имен файлов помогут *библиотеки*, но на самом деле ничего страшного в таких длинных командных строках нет.

Answer (score 0):

Да, `g++ main.cpp file.cpp` - правильно.

> если в дальнейшем в файлов будет от 10 и все их нужно прописывать после (g++ main.cpp ...)?

Начните использовать IDE, тогда не будет необходимости ничего вручную прописывать.